# images in bootstrap modal not showing up on mobile

Tags: iphone, css, mobile, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

i'm working on a restaurant's website and have run into this annoying problem when visiting the site on my phone. here's what i see: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNbFQ.png (reproducible in iOS5, iOS6, *some* Androids)

the menus are .JPG's loading in Twitter Bootstrap modals, and the code looks like this:

```
              <div id="menu" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none; ">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="modal-body">
                    <img src="assets/menus/brunch.jpg">
                  </div>
              </div>
              <a data-toggle="modal" href="#menu" >BRUNCH</a></p>
```

everything loads fine in all desktop browsers, and weirdly enough they appear on the mobile Chrome app in iOS6. i've asked a couple of my Android using friends, and it's about 50%. i have no idea why there doesn't seem to be a pattern. is it an issue with how the images are being called? (i don't think it has anything to do with the modal itself?)

help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok, turns out the images were CMYK, which mobile does not like. changed to RGB and everything loads fine now!